# How to increase maxJsonLength in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I want to read a huge JSON file in my C# (Console Application) code and I am using **Newtonsoft.Json** and **System.Web.Script.Serialization**. However, I face this error. `Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.`. How is it possible to fix this problem?

Comment: I believe you can set it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it when you initiate a serializer

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
```

you can do it in web config

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

or normal config if you do not have a web app.

However, if you see this kind of issue you should maybe should start thinking of using a different transport layer serialization, ex: protobuf.

Comment: Thank you so much. The first part of your code can fix this problem.